# Multiple arguments to binary fold expression?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, fold

I am trying to write variadic template printing using fold expressions rather than template recursion.

Currently I have

```cpp
template <typename... Ts, typename charT, typename traits>
constexpr std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& many_print(std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& os, Ts... args){
  os << '{';
  (os << ... << args);
  return os << '}';
}
```

For a call to `many_print(1, 2);`, the output is `{12}`.

I would like to have my output be `{1, 2}`.

The only close attempt I have made is

```cpp
template <typename... Ts, typename charT, typename traits>
constexpr std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& many_print(std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& os, Ts... args){
  os << '{';
  (os << ... << ((void)(os << ", "), args));
  return os << '}';
}
```

This uses the comma operator to print `", "` for every arg. Unfortunately due to the sequencing order, the comma prints before the arg, resulting in `{, 1, 2}`;

Are there any solutions without using template recursion?

I understand that having n-1 commas will be an issue. I would appreciate if I could even get code that outputs `{1, 2, }`.

Comment: "*I would appreciate if I could even get code that outputs {1, 2, }.*" If that's what you want, why not just reverse the order in your comma expression. Put the `args` part first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, where nothing is being computed, you can just use the comma operator for the fold itself:

```
((os << args << ", "),...)
```

With a state variable trick, you can even omit one comma:

```
int n=0;
((os << (n++ ? ", " : "") << args),...);
```

Comment: Thank you! I kept trying to use `<<` as a binary operator, not realizing I could use it as a unary operator.

Comment: @Nathan29006781: It’s not a unary operator, although one can sort of consider `os <<` as one such.